# How to get the count of records for a django model property

Tags: django, django-models

I need to display the count of get_followers and get_following for my model in my admin.

My model is called application and each app has a number of followers and following. I need to display the count for the followers and following. I tried to use the .count function in a separate function but I am missing something.

This is what I have now:

```
class Application(TimeStampModel):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='CI Name', max_length=100, unique=True)
    relationships = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Relationship',
                                           symmetrical=False,
                                           related_name='related_to')

    def get_following(self):

        return ", ".join(str(x) for x in self.get_relationships(RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING))
```

## getting the count of "get_following"

```
    def get_following_count(self):

        return ", ".join(str(x) for x in self.get_relationships(RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING).count())
```

## but the above doesn't work.

```
    def get_followers(self):
        return ",".join(str(x) for x in self.get_related_to(RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING))
    def get_friends(self):
        return self.relationships.filter(
            to_apps__status=RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING,
            to_apps__from_application=self,
            from_apps__status=RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING,
            from_apps__to_application=self)

    def get_friends_display(self):
        return ", ".join(str(x) for x in self.get_friends())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done.

```
def get_following_count(self):
    count_get_following = self.get_relationships(RELATIONSHIP_FOLLOWING).count()
    return count_get_following
```